# undefined reference to `xdo_new(char const*)'

Tags: c++, g++

I try to invoke libxdo in cpp like following:

```
#include <xdo.h>

int main() {
    xdo_t *xdo = xdo_new(NULL);
    return  0;
}
```

and run `g++ /home/roroco/Dropbox/try/c/try/main.cpp -lxdo`, it raise

```
/tmp/ccWh9hHs.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `xdo_new(char const*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Please tell me what happen?

**Update**: I have install libxdo but still get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Your compilation flags are in the wrong order.

Write `-lxdo` *after* `main.cpp`.

Comment: it didn't duplicate, when i `g++ /home/roroco/Dropbox/try/c/try/main.cpp -lxdo`, It still raise error